What's wrong in this proof- $\frac{\tan(3A)}{\tan(A)}$ coming out to be $1$
I was looking to simplify the expression
$$k = \frac{\tan(3A)}{\tan(A)}$$
I proceeded as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\tan(3A) &= \frac{\sin(3A)}{\cos(3A)} \\[4pt]
\sin(3A) &= 3\sin(A) - 4\sin^3(A) \\[4pt]
\cos(3A) &= 4\cos^3(A) - 3\cos(A) 
\end{align}$$
I further simplified it wholly as
$$\begin{align}
\tan(3A) &= \left(\frac{\sin(3A)}{\sin(A)}\right)\left(\frac{\cos(A)}{\cos(3A)}\right) \tag1\\[4pt]
&= \left(\frac{3 \sin(A) - 4 \sin^3(A)}{\sin(A)}\right)\left(\frac{\cos(A)}{4 \cos^3(A) - 3  \cos(A)}\right) \tag2 \\[4pt]
&= (3 - 4 \sin^2(A))\left(\frac{1}{4 \cos^2(A) - 1}\right) \tag3 \\[4pt]
&= (3 - 4 \sin^2(A))\left(\frac{1}{3 - 4 \sin^2(A)}\right) \tag4 \\[4pt]
&= 1 \tag5
\end{align}$$
I am baffled by this. This result obviously does not hold true. Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

There is something wrong between lines 2 and 3. Specifically, $\frac{\cos A}{4 \cos^3 A - 3 \cos A} \ne \frac{1}{4 \cos^2 A - 1}$.

@peterwhy Is suppose that the OP meant $\left(3-4\sin^2A\right)\left(\frac1{3-4\sin^2A}\right)=1$.

@peterwhy Sorry, a typing error. Edited.

As pointed out in a previous comment, there’s an error in the previous line too. You wrote $1$ where you should have written $3$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\tan(3A)}{\tan A} &= \left(\frac{\sin(3A)}{\sin(A)}\right)\left(\frac{\cos(A)}{\cos(3A)}\right) \tag1\\[4pt]
&= \left(\frac{3 \sin(A) - 4 \sin^3(A)}{\sin(A)}\right)\left(\frac{\cos(A)}{4 \cos^3(A) - 3  \cos(A)}\right) \tag2 \\[4pt]
&= (3 - 4 \sin^2(A))\left(\frac{1}{4 \cos^2(A) - \color{red}3}\right) \tag3 \\[4pt]
&= (3 - 4 \sin^2(A))\left(\frac{1}{1 - 4 \sin^2(A)}\right) \tag4 \\
\end{align}$$
